# Next value in a falling sequence

Tags: calculation-puzzle, number-sequence

Every month the price of a particular commodity falls in this order:

> **1024, 640, 400, 250, $\ldots$**

What is the next value?
Please help me to find pattern of this sequence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each subsequent number is $\frac58$ of the previous one.

Answer (score 7):

According to the On-line encyclopedia of integer sequences
https://oeis.org/A084912

> A084912:$~~$  a(1) = 1024;$~~$ a(n) = 5*a(n-1)/8.
>
> Puzzle: a man offered to sell me a car two years ago for \$1024; a year later his price was \$640; a little while after that he asked \$400; and last week he was willing to sell for \$250. The next time he reduces I shall buy. At what price will I buy the car if he makes consistent reductions?
>
> Answer: a(5) = 1250/8 = \$156.25 (not an integer).

Comment: Stunning to find this on the OEIS. Also, my first exposure to a `dumb` sequence.